# Bokeh vbar figure with reversed y-axis

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

I'm trying to create a vbar figure in Bokeh 1.1 for survey ratings data that follow the reverse order that one would normally expect. In this data set "Excellent" is a 1.0 (the highest score) and "Extremely Poor" is 5.0 (the lowest score) and I am plotting the average values. Hence, I'd like to have a bar that goes from 5.0 at the bottom of the chart up to the top of 1.25, or whatever the average value is.

In the code below I specified:

```
y_range = (5,1)
```

which puts the axis in the right direction but also unfortunately (and as expected) flips the vbar so it comes down from the top.

In another place I used:

```
fig.y_range.flipped = True
```

as an ad hoc solution for a similar challenge with a line figure, but when applied to a vbar this still produces bars that come down from the top of the chart, whereas I still want the bar to come up from the bottom.

Here's a quick version of the code I've been using:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import show, output_file, output_notebook
from bokeh.transform import dodge

Years = [2010, 2011, 2010, 2012, 2011, 2013, 2013]
ratings_df = pd.DataFrame(Years)
ratings_df.columns = ['Years']
ratings_df['Math_Mean_Ratings'] = [1.0, 2.0, 1.5, 3.0, 5.0, 1.0, 2.0]
ratings_df['German_Mean_Ratings'] = [3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 1.5, 2.0]
ratings_df

table1 = pd.pivot_table(ratings_df, values=['Math_Mean_Ratings', 'German_Mean_Ratings'], index='Years', aggfunc=np.mean)

fig_title = 'Instructor Ratings: 2010 to 2013'
fig = figure(plot_width=600, plot_height=300, title = fig_title, y_range = (5,1))

fig.vbar(x=dodge('Years', -0.2, range=p2.x_range), width = 0.3, top='Math_Mean_Ratings', source=table1, color='deepskyblue')
fig.vbar(x=dodge('Years', 0.2, range=p2.x_range), width = 0.3, top='German_Mean_Ratings', source=table1, color='midnightblue')

show(fig)
```

The ultimate output will have a lot of years and a lot of different averages for each year and I'll have to frequently update it, so I'd rather use a mid-level plotting interface like vbar than create independent rectangles for all the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bokeh `vbar` has `bottom=0` as the default so if you flip the axis, and leave that default, then it only makes sense for the bar to flip as well. Presumably you would want to set `bottom=6` (or whatever makes sense as the "lowest" value on your scale).

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize there was such a simple solution. That's just what I needed: now everything works perfectly!